# Python: conditional build depending on environment

Tags: python, build, mpi, distutils, software-distribution

Using `distutils`, how can I make a conditional build depending on the environment. I have two versions of a script, which I am going to use as an entry point. Depending on whether `mpich` is installed or not, I want to use one of them.  It could be easily done with `Makefiles` in the C-family projects (see [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) feature), I expect similar tool for Python.

By doing conditional builds, I am trying to avoid an error that arises when I am trying to launch a script that uses mpi functions in the system where mpi is not installed. Is it possible to check if mpich is installed during the build procedure - for instance in the setup configuration file - and pick the right version of the script as an entry point?

Comment: That would be possible only for source distribution (`python setup.py sdist`) because they are built on the target host during `pip install`. Other distribution types (eggs and wheels) are built at the source host so it'd be meaningless to check mpich there. You'd better change how your scripts work (test for mpich at runtime) and build wheels.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly. Are you talking about a pure python package? I think it would be easier to detect mpi during runtime so that if people install mpi afterwards, they can still use the MPI functionality you offer. You could check the first time your module gets imported and define the functions based on your findings during runtime. If this is not helping you, could you describe a bit more what you are planning? Maybe a tiny example?

Comment: Yes I am talking about a pure python script. This solution seems doable, except it does not look very attractive form the code style point of view - the script becomes very large with many branches, hardly readable.